# Seleniumwire is not supporting Chrome version 116

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, seleniumwire

I'm have a problem when using Seleniumwire.
I need seleniumwire in using its proxy authentication feature. But recently, Chrome has been updated to version 116 and Seleniumwire still just supporting maximum version Chromedriver 114.

[Maximum supported driver is 114](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbuT8.png)
[Current Seleniumwire version 5.1.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIZYa.png)

Anyone knows when will Seleniumwire will be updated? or is there any way to use "proxy authentication" without Seleniumwire?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

For proxy with auth, you can use [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase):

`pip install seleniumbase`, then run this with `python`:

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(proxy="USER:PASS@IP:PORT") as sb:
    sb.driver.get("https://whatismyip.com")
    sb.sleep(6)
```

If you're using undetected-chromedriver mode with that, add `uc=True`:

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True, proxy="USER:PASS@IP:PORT") as sb:
    sb.driver.get("https://whatismyip.com")
    sb.sleep(6)
```

Comment: Hi Michael, Thank you for your answer and your contribution in seleniumbase. Does sb.driver provides same functionalities like webdriver? Is it fine if we replace driver with sb.driver in the existing codebase?

Comment: sb.driver has the same methods and functionality as “driver”. They can be swapped.

Comment: Well, that is great Michael. For me, It solved the issue of proxies and run smoothly. Thank you very much for your efforts for this great library. I will be using it from now onwards for every scraping related projects. :)